# How to limit for loop to print first few element from list in terms of their value in python?

Tags: python, list, loops, element

I would like to limit for loop to print first few element from list in terms of their value. For example, if i < 6 :

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for i < 6 in list:
    print(i)
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: note: you should NOT name your list `list` as it shadows type `list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on *I would like to limit for loop to print first few element from list in terms of their value* it seems the list is in order so you can use `itertools.takewhile` :

```
from itertools import takewhile

lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] # don't use list

tke = takewhile(lambda x: x< 6, lst)

for t in tke:
    print(t)
1
2
3
4
5
```

If you want a list use `list(...)`.

```
print(list(takewhile(lambda x: x< 6, lst))) # good reason why we should not use list as a variable name 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Why not just use `tke = [x for x in lst if x < 6]`?

Comment: @IanAuld, why would you iterate over the full list to get the first few? takewhile will end as soon as it meets a value that does not satisfy the condition

Answer (score 1):

```
In [9]: L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

In [10]: for i in L:
   ....:     if i<6:
   ....:         print(i)
   ....:         
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Is it not possible to put this condition into the loop ?

Comment: @Gillesbert, not for printing a value.  If you wanted to select all the values < 6, you could do that with a list comprehension, e.g. new_list = [i for i in L if i < 6], and then print new_list